# Machine Learning Classification with only binary numbers

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science

I have 50 predictors and 1 target variable. All my predictors and target variable are only binary numbers 0s and 1s. I am performing my analysis using R.

I will be implementing four algorithms.
    1. RF
    2. Log Reg
    3. SVM
    4. LDA

I have the following questions:
I convert them all into factors. How should i treat my variables priorly, before feeding them into my other algorithms.

I used the caret package to train my model, it takes very much time. I do practice ML regularly, but I dont know how to proceed with all variable being binary.
How to remove collinear variables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All binary predictors in a classification task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46844180/all-binary-predictors-in-a-classification-task)

Comment: @Headpoint , can you answer this

Comment: You should try to make the questions narrower - there are a larger number of classifiers and ways to handle data.  If the variables are in fact categorical variables, you should convert them into factors so they will not be treated as numerical variables.  If you are not sure how to proceed with categorical data, best to read some intro article. I imagine there are a lot of machine learning algorithms for this type of data.

Comment: I am trying a number of algorithms, all of them above, also converted them into factors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not mostly R-user, but Python. Bet there is common approach:
1. Check you columns. Remove column if number of zeroes or ones is > 95% of total amount (you can try 2.5% or even 1% later).
2. Run simple Random Forest by default and get feature importance. Columns that are unnecessary you can process with LDA.
3. Check target column. If it's highly unbalanced try oversampling or downsampling. Or use classification methods that can handle unbalanced target column (like XGBoost).

For Linear regression you'll need to calculate correlation matrix and remove correlated columns. Other methods can live without it.

Please check SVM (or SVC) does it support all features to be boolean or not. But usually it works very good with binary classification.

Also I advice to try Neural Network.

PS About collinear variables. I wrote a code on Python for my project. That's simple - you can do it:
 - plot correlation matrix
 - find pairs that have correlation over some threshold
 - remove column that have *lower* correlation with target variable (you can also check that columns you want to remove is not important, otherwise try other way, probably union columns)

In my code I ran this algorithm iteratively for different thresholds: from 0.99 down to 0.9. Works good.